# How to print when item in arraylist is removed in java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'm basically looking for some sort of either line of code or loop that I could use to just print text whenever an item of an array list is removed or haven't been able to find an answer.

```
while (arraylist.remove()=true)
{
    //text
}
```

Obviously this code won't work but that's the idea I'm trying to go with.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To print text, call `System.out.println("text");` --- If that wasn't your question, then please edit the question and clarify what you need.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Your question is unclear.

Comment: So I know how to print text, I just only want to print a line of text saying something like item has been deleted whenever something is removed from the arraylist i have

Comment: Do you want to print items in a list, or would you rather have a debug log when stuff is added or removed from your list

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that code snippet is already one way: when **your** code invokes the `remove()` method, then you can check the result of that operation - from its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> true if this list contained the specified element

Of course, if you want to "understand" during remove that something is removed, you are always free to **implement** the List interface yourself, or to extend say [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) and add code to the various `remove()` methods.

( and just to be precise: the only reason your example code doesn't work is that you are doing `remove() = true` but should be using `== true` - or even better `if (someList.remove(someObj))`)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following method to your class (you pass list containing an object and object itself as arguments). After that you do the proper check (note that to check if the variable stores true you should use `==` instead of `=`, as the second one is an assignment operator):

```
public static <T> boolean removeAndPrint(List<T> list, T elem) {
    boolean result = list.remove(elem);
    if (result == true) {
        System.out.println("Item removed");
    } 
    return result;
}
```